# Why can't I format a 10 GB partition in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, format, disk-management

I had Ubuntu installed in a 10 GB partition of a 120 GB hard drive on my laptop.

I then installed Windows 7 on the 110 GB partition.

Now inside Windows 7, I want to reformat the 10 GB partition and use it for Windows.

I go to Computer, Manage, Disk Management, deleted the 10 GB volumne, then choose "New Simple Volumne", all default values, but it says "There is not enough space."

**How can I format and use this partition for Windows?**

[image]

How can I create a partition from this free space? When I **right click** on the empty space, these are the options I get:

[image]

If I try to **delete** the free space, it tells me:

[image]

## Answer:

**[Partition Wizard](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)** solved the problem, thanks Rogue!

[image]

Comment: Your welcome and i'm happy it worked out for you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try using a 3rd party application for partitioning your hard drive like [Partition Wizard](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html). Its a free tool.

You could also take a look at this [link](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/07/free-partition-manager-for-windows/)

Comment: GPARTED is also verrrrrrrrry good.

Comment: GPARTED is good no doubts about that, but an a software within windows is an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

From the diagram, it is currently just free space. 
You need to create a partition first and then format it.

Comment: How can I create a partition? When I right click on it I can "create a new simple volume" and "delete partition" which both give me the "not enough space" error.

Comment: I guess it would be the 'create a new simple volume' option.

If you have just delete the Ubuntu partition, you might just need to close Disk Management and re-open it , or perhaps restart the machine before you can make the second change.

Comment: I thought rebooting would fix it as well, but I rebooted and get the same "no space" messages. I also tried creating a 8GB volume but got the same message.

Comment: It is possible that Disk Management is confused about the true state of this drive.
I think I would then go with Roque's suggestion at the very least to get a second opinion of the disk layout.